# How to sort in linq to sql for a joined table?

Tags: asp.net, sorting, linq-to-sql

i have these tables in short:

Table: RPG

Coloumns: RPGID, Name

Table: RPGCharacter

Coloumns: CharID, RPGID, Name

Table: RPGPosts

Coloumns: PostID, CharID, Text, timestamp

So in Database the relation is:
1 RPG has X Characters and 1 Character has X Posts.

I get the information with this code:

```
  public static List<RPG> GetAllRPGs()
    {
        using (RPGDataContext dc = new RPGDataContext())
        {
            return (from a in dc.RPGs where !a.IsHided && !a.IsDeleted select a).ToList();
        }
    }
```

The Problem is:
How to sort these list by the LAST post (TIMESTAMP-Coloumn of the RPGPOst-Table)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've got appropriate navigation properties set up, something like this should work:

```
var results = 
    (from a in dc.RPGs 
     where !a.IsHided && !a.IsDeleted 
     orderby a.Characters.SelectMany(c => c.Posts).Select(p => p.Timestamp).Max()
     select a)
    .ToList();
```

Or possibly:

```
var results = 
    (from a in dc.RPGs 
     where !a.IsHided && !a.IsDeleted 
     orderby a.Characters
              .SelectMany(c => c.Posts)
              .OrderByDescending(p => p.Timestamp)
              .Select(p => p.Timestamp)
              .FirstOrDefault()
     select a)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Can you pls add a method for soprting it when ALLREADY have a list, so assuming i have a list<RPG>, how this would be work with the .sort()-Method?